# Working in localhost & not working online

Tags: php, syntax

Please note that this is not normal syntax error its working offline and not online..

I have below code in PHP which is working perfectly online

```
for($i=0; $i<$colCount;$i++){
    $keys = array_keys($cols)[$i];
    $values = array_values($cols[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":".$keys, $values);
}
```

But when i uploaded the same thing to online i got below error..??

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in XXXXXXXXX on line 183
```

What can be the issue..??

Comment: what version of php on server and local?

Comment: local is PHP/5.4.24
server is PHP/5.3

Comment: $key = array_keys($cols);
$keys = $key[$i];
re write this line ($keys = array_keys($cols)[$i];) like this and check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may have caused due to PHP version.
You need to be running PHP 5.4+ to use shorthand arrays
You can try

```
for($i=0; $i<$colCount;$i++){
    $key = array_keys($cols);
    $keys = $key[$i];
    $values = array_values($cols[$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(":".$keys, $values);
}
```